# Modelling class hierarchy

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, data-modeling

I'm currently modeling a class hierarchy so wanted to check if anyone has any better way of doing this. The problem is as follows:

I have a menu item that has id and icons inside it. Then I can have also menu item that has other sub-menu items (but not icons at the same time). It is basically container for the sub-menu items, but has also id as the real menu item. Current model is something like this:

```
class SubMenuItemOrderNumber{}
class MenuItemTypeId{}
class MenuIconId{}
class MenuIcon{}

interface MenuItemWithoutSubItems{
    MenuItemTypeId getTypeId();
    List<MenuIcon> getIcons();
}

interface MenuItemWithSubItems{
    MenuItemTypeId getTypeId();
    Map<SubMenuItemOrderNumber, SubMenuItem> getOrderNumToSubMenuItem();
}

interface SubMenuItem{
    SubMenuItemOrderNumber getOrderNum();
    List<MenuIcon> getIcons();
}

interface Publishable{
    void suspend();
    void publish();
}

interface ControllableMenuItemWithoutSubItems extends MenuItemWithoutSubItems, Publishable{
    void control(MenuIconId iconId, String iconData);
}

interface ControllableMenuItemWithSubItems extends MenuItemWithSubItems, Publishable{
    void control(SubMenuItemOrderNumber orderNum, MenuIconId iconId, String iconData);
}
```

The problem - it seems like I can make it more generic. Only thing that came to my mind was this variation:

```
    enum EnumSubMenuItemOrderNumber implements SubMenuItemOrderNumber{
    ONLY_IF_MENU_ITEM_WITHOUT_SUB_ITEMS(0);
    private int num;
    EnumSubMenuItemTypeId(num id){
        this.num = num;
    }
    @Override
    public Integer getNum() {
        return num;
    }
}

class RealSubMenuItemOrderNumber implements SubMenuItemOrderNumber{
    private int num;
    @Override
    public Integer getNum() {
        return num;
    }
}

interface SubMenuItemOrderNumber{
    Integer getNum();
}

class MenuItemTypeId{}
class MenuIconId{}
class MenuIcon{}

interface MenuItem{
    MenuItemTypeId getTypeId();
    Map<SubMenuItemOrderNumber, SubMenuItem> getOrderNumToSubMenuItem();
}

interface SubMenuItem{
    SubMenuItemOrderNumber getOrderNum();
    List<MenuIcon> getIcons();
}

interface Publishable{
    void suspend();
    void publish();
}

interface ControllableMenuItem extends MenuItem, Publishable{
    void control(SubMenuItemOrderNumber orderNum, MenuIconId iconId, String iconData);
}
```

But problem with this is that if I want `MenuItemWithoutSubItems` I have to make `MenuItem` and as `SubMenuItemTypeId` in `Map` I have to use `EnumSubMenuItemTypeId.ONLY_IF_MENU_ITEM_WITHOUT_SUB_ITEMS` -> which is a workaround in my case. Classes are simpler, but it still seems more complex than needs to.

Any other options that I could have?

**UPDATE**

This is potential implementation of first use-case:

```
class DefaultMenuItemWithoutSubItems implements MenuItemWithoutSubItems {
    MenuItemTypeId id;
    List<MenuIcon> menuIcons;

    @Override
    public MenuItemTypeId getTypeId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public List<MenuIcon> getIcons() {
        return menuIcons;
    }
}

class DefaultMenuItemWithSubItems implements MenuItemWithSubItems {
    MenuItemTypeId id;
    Map<SubMenuItemOrderNumber, SubMenuItem> orderNumToSubMenuItem;

    @Override
    public MenuItemTypeId getTypeId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<SubMenuItemOrderNumber, SubMenuItem> getOrderNumToSubMenuItem() {
        return orderNumToSubMenuItem;
    }
}

class DefaultSubMenuItem implements SubMenuItem {
    SubMenuItemOrderNumber orderNum;
    List<MenuIcon> menuIcons;

    @Override
    public SubMenuItemOrderNumber getOrderNum() {
        return orderNum;
    }

    @Override
    public List<MenuIcon> getIcons() {
        return menuIcons;
    }
}

class DefaultControllableMenuItemWithoutSubItems implements ControllableMenuItemWithoutSubItems {
    MenuItemTypeId id;
    List<MenuIcon> menuIcons;
    boolean suspended;

    @Override
    public MenuItemTypeId getTypeId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public List<MenuIcon> getIcons() {
        return menuIcons;
    }

    @Override
    public void suspend() {
        suspended = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void publish() {
        suspended = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void control(MenuIconId iconId, String iconData) {
        menuIcons.getById(iconId).replace(new MenuIcon(iconData));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a failed attemt at using the composite pattern.
Here's the idea behind the composite pattern:

You have an interface that you want to expose. For example:

```
public interface MenuItem {
    MenuItemTypeID getType();
    List<MenuIcon> getIcons();
}
```

Next you have a basic implementation:

```
class SingleMenuItem implements MenuItem {
    private MenuItemTypeID id;
    private List<MenuIcon> icons;

    public SingleMenuItem(MenuItemTypeID id, List<MenuIcon> icons) {
        this.id = id;
        this.icons = icons;
    }

    @Override
    public MenuItemTypeID getType() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public List<MenuIcon> getIcons() {
        return icons;
    }
}
```

And here comes the magic. We also want to have a grouping implementation, but the composite pattern dictates that it should behave exactly like a normal MenuItem. So the class could look something like this:

```
class MenuItemGroup implements MenuItem {
    private MenuItemTypeID id;
    private List<MenuItem> subMenuItems;

    public MenuItemGroup(MenuItemTypeID id, List<MenuItem> subMenuItems) {
        this.id = id;
        this.subMenuItems = subMenuItems;
    }

    @Override
    public MenuItemTypeID getType() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public List<MenuIcon> getIcons() {
        List<MenuIcon> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (MenuItem subItem : subMenuItems) {
            result.addAll(subItem.getIcons());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now if we have some `MenuItem item`, we can get all the icons in that menu item. We don't care if it is a `SingleMenuItem`, or if it's a `MenuItemGroup`, since both will just return all the icons they contain.

Note that we can also have a group that contains more groups that all contain some SingleMenuItems, or a combination of SingleMenuItems with more groups of MenuItems. We still use it like any other MenuItem.

How useful this is in your context I have no idea though ...

Comment: I'm aware of Composite pattern. The problem with your implementation is that you lost SubMenuItemOrderNumber. Also, subMenuItems inside MenuItemGroup have MenuItemTypeId, but this property does not belong to this sub items inside MenuItemGroup (SubItems are not actually MenuItems in my Model).

Comment: Hmm, so those were actually important, not just a design artifact... Could you provide a concrete example perhaps? Since you only have interfaces now that I don't understand how they would ever be used practically.

Comment: I just added potential implementation. For now, I think that I need to access this 2 objects separately. I would store them in 2 different Lists, and then I would have to know which one has no sub items and which one has (since on ones with sub-items i can actually do operations on those sub-items).